# Incorrect computation of Euler Sum using Complex Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, residue-calculus, euler-sums

First of all, I know this is a long and intimidating question, but I'm sure anyone with a little bit of complex analysis experience can answer it, so please don't turn away.

In [this paper](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf) by Flajolet and Salvy, they use the series representation of the Digamma function and the fact that, if $p$ is a nonnegative integer, as $s\to p$,
$$\psi(-s)+\gamma\sim \frac{1}{s-p}+H_p+...$$
to state that as $s\to p$,
$$(\psi(-s)+\gamma)^2\sim \frac{1}{(s-p)^2}+\frac{2H_p}{s-p}+...$$
and so if $r(s)$ is a function with no poles or zeroes at the positive integers,
$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\space\space (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^2 r(s)_{s=p}
&= \text{Res}\space\space \frac{r(s)}{(s-p)^2}+\frac{2H_p\space r(s)}{s-p}_{s=p}\\
&= \text{Res}\space\space \frac{r(s)}{(s-p)^2}+\frac{2H_p\space r(s)}{s-p}\\
&= \lim_{s\to p} \frac{d}{ds}r(s)_{s=p}+\lim_{s\to p}2H_pr(s)\\
&= r'(p)+2H_pr(p)\\
\end{align}$$
As long as $r(s)$ is $\mathcal O(s^{-2})$ at infinity, the integral $\oint (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^2 r(s) ds$ around a circle with radius approaching infinity should go to zero, meaning that the sum of all residues of $(\psi(-s)+\gamma)^2 r(s)$ should equal zero. Thus, if $q_i$ are the poles of $r(s)$, we have
$$\color{green}{\sum_{p=0}^\infty (r'(p)+2H_p r(p))+\sum_{q_i}\text{Res} (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^2 r(s)_{s=q_i}=0}$$
Which is the result given in the paper. However, I tried to extend this further by saying that near its poles,
$$(\psi(-s)+\gamma)^3\sim \frac{1}{(s-p)^3}+\frac{3H_p}{(s-p)^2}+\frac{3H_p^2}{s-p}...$$
Which should yield
$$\text{Res}\space\space (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^3 r(s)_{s=p}=\frac{1}{2}r''(p)+3H_p r'(p)+3H_p^2 r(p)$$
and the summatory formula
$$\color{red}{\sum_{p=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{2}r''(p)+3H_p r'(p)+3H_p^2 r(p)\bigg)+\sum_{q_i}\text{Res} (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^3 r(s)_{s=q_i}=0}$$
But this isn't what the paper says. The paper says that
$$\color{green}{\sum_{p=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{1}{2}r''(p)-3r(p)\zeta(2)+3H_p r'(p)+3H_p^2 r(p)-3H_p^{(2)}r(p)\bigg)+\sum_{q_i}\text{Res} (\psi(-s)+\gamma)^3 r(s)_{s=q_i}=0}$$

Why is this so? Where was my mistake?

Comment: For the third power, you also need the $(s-p)$ term, $\psi(-s) + \gamma = \frac{1}{s-p} + H_p + B(s-p) + \dotsc$, and that gives you a $\frac{3B}{s-p}$.

Comment: Oh, I see... I didn't include all of the terms that have poles. Thank you for taking the time to tell me my mistake! Post it an an answer and I'll happily upvote.

Comment: I'm going to bed now, not enough time to write an answer. You can answer your own question.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $f$ has a simple pole - we assume that the residue is $1$ for simplicity of notation, the general case follows by multiplication with a constant - at $p$, write

$$f(s) = \frac{1}{s-p} + g(s)$$

with $g$ holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $p$. Then by the binomial theorem

$$f(s)^m = \sum_{k = 0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \frac{g(s)^k}{(s-p)^{m-k}}\,,\tag{$\ast$}$$

and to compute the residue of $f(s)^m r(s)$ for a holomorphic $r$ with a zero of order $0 \leqslant\mu < m$ at $p$, we need the terms for $k \leqslant m - \mu - 1$ on the right hand side of $(\ast)$, since all these may contain a term $\frac{c}{s-p}$ with $c\neq 0$ in their Laurent expansion about $p$. Writing $r(s) = (s-p)^{\mu} u(s)$, we obtain

$$f(s)^m\cdot r(s) = \sum_{k = 0}^{m - \mu - 1} \binom{m}{k} \frac{g(s)^k u(s)}{(s-p)^{m-\mu-k}} + \sum_{k = m-\mu}^{m} \binom{m}{k}(s-p)^{k+\mu-m}g(s)^ku(s)$$

where the second sum is holomorphic at $p$, and hence
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res} \bigl(f^m(s) r(s)\bigr)_{s = p}
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{m - \mu - 1} \binom{m}{k} \operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{g(s)^ku(s)}{(s-p)^{m-\mu-k}}\biggr)_{s = p} \\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{m - \mu - 1} \binom{m}{k} \frac{1}{(m-\mu-k-1)!} \biggl(\frac{d}{ds}\biggr)^{m-\mu-k-1}\bigl(g(s)^ku(s)\bigr)\biggr\rvert_{s = p}\,.
\end{align}

For $m = 3$ and $\mu = 0$ that is

$$\operatorname{Res}\bigl(f(s)^3r(s)\bigr)_{s = p} = \frac{1}{2}r''(p) + 3\bigl(g'(p)r(p) + g(p)r'(p)\bigr) + 3g(p)^2r(p)\,.$$

Comment: Thanks again! $\space$